# Laravel 5.5 set SQL variable

Tags: php, sql, laravel, pdo

I'm getting an error while trying to set a SQL variable in Laravel 5.5.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "SET": syntax error
```

**SQL**

```
SET @i = 0;
```

The same SQL runs fine in phpMyAdmin.

**Things I've tried which all cause the same aforementioned error**

```
DB::statement("SET @i = 0");
```

---

```
DB::select(DB::raw("SET @i = 0;"));
```

---

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$pdo->prepare("SET @i = 0;");
$pdo->execute();
```

**UPDATE**

I found my mistake, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was only getting this error in my tests where I use SQLite in memory. SQLite doesn't support this SQL syntax. Will have to get rid of that test, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this:

```
 DB::statement(DB::raw('SET @i = 0'));
```